# Creating a new XSD Schema in VS 2013

Tags: xml, xsd, visual-studio-2013

This used to be the easiest thing in the world but I just can't work out how to use the designer to add nodes to an XSD schema.  In the past, you just added a new complex type to the design surface and added more simple or complex types to that type and it was job done.

Now you get presented with a home screen with a number of options on the canvas.  I basically need to add a new Global Complex Type so I click the Add link next to that option and it takes me to Graph View where I am instructed to "Visualize nodes in your XML Schema by dragging them from the Xml Schema Explorer onto the design surface".

But in the XML Schema Explorer I don't see any nodes (other than "myschema.xsd") because I haven't created any. Seems like a catch 22.

The only way I can see of doing this is to go into the XML Editor view and manually add complex types myself. There must be a visual way of doing this via the designer?

Comment: Hmmm... the more time I waste on exploring this "designer" the more I come to the conclusion that its only use is in viewing an XSD & that it is not much of a designer at all. It looks like the only way to actually EDIT XML schema is to dive into the XML of it, using XML editor.  Complete rubbish... I sure the older VS XSD editors were much more useful.

Comment: If you install the BizTalk 2013 developer SDK then you get a decent XSD editor.  Probably overkill to address this though.

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio does not allow creating of new nodes, but it does have intelli-sense in xsd and to be honest all these graphic interface which people pay for are a waste of money because you can do the job by hand in code far quicker and easier. Though Microsoft does seem to be backward in this area